# String Containing only Vowels

Tags: string, vector, c++14

Suppose I have a vector of string and it contains strings (aei,ou,a). I want to concatenate them in O(n). After concatination it will become (aeiou,aeia,oua). I want to do concatination in one for loop. How to do it?

Comment: Please be more specific about the rules that you want the concatenation to follow. Also, is this homework?

Answer (score 0):

Mind you, I haven't checked this, i just made this on the fly. but this sounds like its what you want.

```
public void variableStrings(arr[] strings) {
List<string> newList = new List<string>();
   for(int i = 0; i+1 < strings.Length -1; i++)
   {
      newList.add(string.Format("{0}{1}",strings[i],strings[i+1]));
   }
}
```